# How to speed up the query transactions for large records in Django, if we are visiting multiple classes to achieve this?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

I'm trying to show user profiles suggestion for a loggedIn user based on the tags he/she follows, In my case i have to travel to User_Interests_Tag class to get all the tags, next visit Post_Tag class to get all the posts for each of the tag(loop), once i have the all the postId's, visit the Post class to get each unique user and append it to a profile(List) and used paginator to limit the profiles sent to the client.
How can i achieve this without using ***for*** loops to increase the overall efficiency and response time from the server?

models:

```
        class User_Interests_Tag(models.Model): # User Suggestions Tag to User link
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        priority = models.FloatField(default=0.0) 
    
        class Post_Tag(models.Model): # Post Media Link
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True) 
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Post(models.Model): 
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=500, default="unknown", null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=512 , null = True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

here is the snippet what i want to achieve :

```
    #looping through each tag
    for user_interests_tag in user_interests_tags:
        #user_post_tags = Post_Tag.objects.in_bulk(user_interests_tags) (used bulk but no luck) 
        user_post_tags.extend(list(Post_Tag.objects.filter(tag_id = user_interests_tag).values_list('post_id', flat=True)))
    profiles = []
    #looping through each tag id 
    for user_post_tag in user_post_tags:
            #getting the user from post class
            user = Post.objects.get(id = user_post_tag)
            #checking if already follows and if  already their in user profiles array
            if user not in profiles and not User_Follow.objects.filter( owner_id = user_id.id, user_id = user.user_id):
                        profiles.append(user)
    #paginating 6 per request
    paginator = Paginator(profiles,6)
    limited_profiles = paginator.page(page)
    return limited_profiles
```

Any leads very much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: Sure please check above , i just edited it with the models!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(post_tag_set__tag__in=user_interests_tags) 
    & ~Q(user__in=User_Follow.objects.filter(owner_id=user_id.id).values('user'))
).distinct()

paginator = Paginator(posts, 6)
limited_profiles = paginator.page(page)

return limited_profiles
```

To expand on this:

```
Q(post_tag_set__tag__in=user_interests_tags)
```

The above will filter all `Post`s that have `Post_Tag`s with `Tag`s matching `user_interests_tags`.

```
~Q(user__in=User_Follow.objects.filter(owner_id=user_id.id).values('user'))
```

The above will also filter `Post`s with a `user` that doesn't match any `User_Follow` objects based on owner id filter you currently have.

Comment: Hey thank you for the clear cut explanation , in this line Q(post_tag_set__tag__in=user_interests_tags) i'm getting an error saying that : Cannot resolve keyword 'post_tag_set' into field.

Comment: This statement is actually filtering out the Tag's ids but i need get the post's ids to filter out from the post model, please give me lead on how to select post id value in the above mentioned statement. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey @BrianDestura the below code works for me && significantly decreased my response time for large records, Please do let me know if you have any other way to optimize it further more. looking forward for your reply!                                      `posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(id__in = Post_Tag.objects.filter(Q(tag__in = User_Interests_Tag.objects.filter(user_id = user_id.id).values_list('tag_id', flat=True))).values_list('post_id', flat=True) ) 
&
~Q(user__in=User_Follow.objects.filter(owner_id=user_id.id).values('user'))).distinct().order_by('-id')`

Comment: Oh great to hear that it improved! You can substitute `post_tag_set` with the actual `related_name` you are using (the reverse accessor from post to post tag) (maybe try just `post_tag`). Essentially your current code is doing the same thing to the answer I posted.

Comment: Sure @Brian i will try it, Thank you so much , I really appreciate your time and I hope you have a great day sir :)